# Show text on hover using just JS

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, show

I tried a CSS solution but won't work (I believe this is a bug with the software or server I'm using). Now looking for java solution.

Put simply, I wish text to display on hover.

Here's what I've come up with but it won't work (I'm a noob)....

```
<DIV class="spire-menu">
    <DIV class="menu-item">Hello1</DIV>
    <DIV>Hello2</DIV></DIV>
```

The plan is to have Hello2 displayed perminantly. Hello1 will only display on hover.

```
$(".spire-menu").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.menu-item').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.menu-item').hide();
});
```

Comment: If something as simple as [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/aZ2qY/) wont work, what makes you think jQuery will ?

Comment: @adeneo: Because jQuery does all the things.

Comment: @Blender - oh, forgot that part, even if it's obvious !

Comment: Yes - CSS is easier. As per the OP, having trouble with CSS due to potential software issue. In any event, I've already used java elsewhere and it works great. I know it's not preferred, but I just need a workaround at this point. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is better to use instead of JQuery. But if it doesn't work, here is the JQuery solution

```
<div class="spire-menu">
    <DIV class="menu-item" style="display:none;">Hello1</DIV>
     <DIV style="position:absolute;top:25px;">Hello2</DIV>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".spire-menu").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".menu-item").fadeIn();
    }
                    ,function(){
                        $(this).find(".menu-item").fadeOut();
                    }
                   );        
});
```

[Here's the working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shijukbabu/BC4eY/965/)

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Great work @Shiju. Only modification I require is text needs to stay in it's original position and not bump up and down with hide/display. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Then position your div. See the update. Also I have updated working demo. You can set the position of div according to your need.